# Convert Series index to df columns after groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap, multi-index

The following code

```py
testIDs.groupby(
    ['id', pd.TimeGrouper(key='date',freq='20s')]
)['quadrant'].value_counts()
```

Gives me:

```
Out[128]: 
id    date                 quadrant
2617  2019-10-08 18:47:40  4           1
      2019-10-08 18:54:00  1           1
                           3           1
      2019-10-08 18:54:40  0           1
                           3           1  
      2019-10-08 18:56:20  3           1
      2019-10-08 18:59:20  2           1
      2019-10-08 19:05:40  1           1
      2019-10-08 19:06:20  1           2
                           4           1
      2019-10-08 19:06:40  0           1
                           1           1
      2019-10-08 19:07:00  2           2
                           0           1
                           3           1
      2019-10-08 19:13:40  2           1
      2019-10-08 19:14:20  0           1
                           2           1
      2019-10-08 19:16:40  3           1
      2019-10-08 19:18:40  1           3
                           0           2
                           3           2
                           2           1
      2019-10-08 19:19:00  4           3
                           1           2
                           0           1
                           2           1
      2019-10-08 19:19:20  4           6
                           2           1
      2019-10-08 19:19:40  3           2
                                      ..
2855  2019-10-08 19:44:20  4           4
                           1           2
                           2           2
      2019-10-08 19:44:40  4           8
      2019-10-08 19:45:00  4           3
                           1           2
                           2           2
                           0           1
      2019-10-08 19:45:20  4           7
                           2           1
      2019-10-08 19:45:40  4           4
                           2           2
                           1           1
                           3           1
      2019-10-08 19:46:00  1           3
                           4           2
                           0           1
                           2           1
                           3           1
      2019-10-08 19:46:20  2           4
                           1           3
                           4           1
      2019-10-08 19:46:40  1           3
                           2           3
                           3           1
                           4           1
      2019-10-08 19:47:00  0           2
                           1           1
                           2           1
                           4           1
   Name: quadrant, Length: 714, dtype: int64
```

The final output should be a heatmap with date as X axis and id as Y axis, with the Quadrant counts as values. I want to compare the id's according to the quadrants and the counts of quadrants in time.

For that, how do I transform this series to a dataframe, with the multiindex as df columns?

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Add `.reset_index()` after your `groupby` code.

Comment: but this only returns the column, not the id, date, and quadrant from the index. How can I also get those into df columns?

Comment: The reset index would need an aggregation func. I added an answer with the entire code. It would be beneficial if you could share a sample, reproducible code with your data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all you need is to reset the index, and use an aggregation to return the dataframe entirely:

```py
testIDs.groupby(
    ['id', pd.TimeGrouper(key='date',freq='20s')]
).agg({'quadrant':'count'}).reset_index()
```

**Edit**: If your quadrant is also to be grouped:

```py
testIDs.groupby(
    ['id', pd.TimeGrouper(key='date',freq='20s'), 'quadrant']
).count().reset_index()
```

Note that if you have many columns, it will count for all columns.

Comment: This is great! Last, but it loses the original quadrant column? The logic is exactly what I aimed for!

Comment: Oh so it seems that the quadrant should be part of your `groupby` then, is that so? Are you counting every quadrant for every date period for every id?

Comment: You are great, thanks so much! That is exactly what i try, create a new column with the counts of every quadrant for every date period for every id. Is that implementable in the same line of code?

Comment: Yeap that should be the second part of the answer.